# ClassB=[ClassA,ClassA,ClassA] cant print ClassB and index it. Python

Tags: python, list, class

I want to make a deck out of tarjeta, but i cant seem to print it and i cant use index. The Class Tarjeta works but when i append it to Mazo and print it, it gives me the same thing as if i didnt have the **str** thingy.
paises_por_tarjeta is a {}

```
class Tarjeta(object):      #this is ClassA
        """Implementacion de una tarjeta de pais."""
        def __init__(self, pais=None, tipo=0):
                """Constructor desde pais y tipo."""
                self.pais = pais
                self.tipo = tipo

        def __str__(self):
                """Representacion grafica."""
                return "(%s,%s)"%(self.pais, NOMBRE_TARJETAS[self.tipo])

class Mazo(object):        #ClassB
        """Implementacion del mazo de tarjetas de pais."""
        def __init__(self, paises_por_tarjeta):           #paises_por_tarjeta is a {} that has the suit as key and countries as value
                """Creacion desde un diccionario de paises segun tipo.
               Debe inicializar el mazo con todas las tarjetas mezcladas."""
                self.mazo=[]
                for i in range(0,4):      
                        for x in paises_por_tarjeta[i]:
                                self.mazo.append(Tarjeta(x,i))
                max_cartas=len(self.mazo)
                for k in range(max_cartas):             #mezcla el mazo
                        j=random.randrange(k,max_cartas)
                        self.mazo[k],self.mazo[j]=self.mazo[j],self.mazo[k]


        def __str__(self):
                return str(self.mazo)
```

EDIT: here are the NOMBRE_TARJETAS and paises_por_tarjeta:

```
     TARJETA_COMODIN = 0
     TARJETA_GALEON = 1
     TARJETA_GLOBO = 2
     TARJETA_CANON = 3
     NOMBRE_TARJETAS = {
    TARJETA_COMODIN: 'comodin',
    TARJETA_GALEON: 'galeon',
    TARJETA_GLOBO: 'globo',
    TARJETA_CANON: 'canon',
     }

paises_por_tarjeta = {
    TARJETA_COMODIN: ['Argentina', 'Taimir'],
    TARJETA_GALEON: ['Alaska', 'Alemania', 'Borneo', 'Brasil', 'China', 'Gran Bretana', 'Groenlandia', 'Islandia', 'Israel', 'Madagascar', 'Mongolia', 'Nueva York', 'Peru', 'Siberia', 'Suecia', 'Turquia', 'Zaire'],
    TARJETA_GLOBO: ['Chile', 'Colombia', 'Egipto', 'Espana', 'Etiopia', 'Francia', 'Gobi', 'India', 'Iran', 'Italia', 'Kamchatka', 'Rusia', 'Sumatra', 'Uruguay', 'Yukon'],
    TARJETA_CANON: ['Arabia', 'Aral', 'Australia', 'California', 'Canada', 'Japon', 'Java', 'Labrador', 'Malasia', 'Mexico', 'Oregon', 'Polonia', 'Sahara', 'Sudafrica', 'Tartaria', 'Terranova'],
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How have you declared `paises_por_tarjeta` and `NOMBRE_TARJETAS`?

Comment: they come from another module, let me add them.

Comment: Please show the code where you use these classes, show the output, and show what output you were hoping to get instead.

Comment: Can i use pastebin to show you or i have to do the code in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this `__str__` implementation for `Mazo`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str([str(k) for k in self.mazo])
```

**Edit:** If you want your class to support indexing, you can implement the method `__getitem__`:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.mazo[index]
```

Comment: Well that fixed the printing issue thanks, now instead of getting this
[<__main__.Tarjeta object at 0x0000000002E84128>]*50 i get the nice one, but i still cant do something like:
c=Mazo(paises_por_tarjeta)
print c[0]
TypeError: 'Mazo' object does not support indexing

Comment: I think im in love with you right now, i have been all day with this with no idea how to solve it :(
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: veo que sos de peru che. Muchas gracias de nuevo!